# Recall CollectionFS file using Metadata (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am creating an application that allows uploading and displaying of images. The users can upload images and then all of the images are displayed on one page. The biggest issue is that all the images need to display under the name of the owner.

I am using CollectionFS to upload and store the files, this is my storeFile method:

```
Template.queueControl.events({
  'change .fileUploader': function (e) {
      var files = e.target.files;
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          console.log(Meteor.user().username);
          ImageFS.storeFile(f, {username: Meteor.user().username});
      }
  }
});
```

I thought that I would be able to call the file back by using a query like this:

```
Template.studentModal.getImage = function(){
    return ImageFS.find({username: Session.get("studentUsername")});
}
```

The setting and getting of the username work fine and as expected. It will not return any records though.

Thanks,
Skylar

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the "file" to "FS.File" before calling "storeFile". Now you can add metadata like "owner" to an image.

This should work at least in Meteor 0.9:

```
Template.queueControl.events({
  'change .fileUploader': function (e) {
      var files = e.target.files;
      for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          var newFile = new FS.File(files[i]);
          newFile.owner = Meteor.user().username;
          Images.insert(newFile, function(err, fileObj) {});
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is one solution that works well, I do however suggest that if you are uploading large files like videos that you just create a basic CDN uploader in PHP as meteor will slow down and stop responding when 3 or more people are uploading 250MB+ videos.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the userId and subscribe a publication that publishes the shown users, just with usernames.
I use https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite for publication composition.